# Postgres query regex negative doesnt return expected result

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql, pgadmin

I use the query tool in pgAdmin 4 connected a database.
In one of the tables, one of the columns should contain values that are exactly 8 digits (e.g. 12345678).

There are 99 that are exactly 8 digits and 1 that is empty (null).

I would like to create a query that finds the empty one.
The following query returns the 99 records that match:

```
SELECT COUNT (*) FROM my_table WHERE my_column ~ '^[0-9]{8}$';
```

The problem is that when I add ! (negative, just before the tilde), I get 0 matches rather than 1 as expected:

```
SELECT COUNT (*) FROM my_table WHERE my_column !~ '^[0-9]{8}$';
```

Any idea what could go wrong?

Comment: Do you mean you also want to find empty strings? `WHERE my_column ~ '^([0-9]{8})?$'`?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. No, I want to find those that don't match. See @Gordon Linnof answer below, solved my problem.

Answer (score 3):

Almost all comparison operations return `NULL` when the value is `NULL` -- and `WHERE` filters out `NULL`.  So, either add an explicit comparison:

```
WHERE my_column !~ '^[0-9]{8}$' OR my_column IS NULL
```

Or use `COALESCE()`:

```
WHERE COALESCE(my_column, '') !~ '^[0-9]{8}$'
```